# Options inside an input element

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input element:

```
<Input Type=Text Size=27 Name=NewStatus Value=>
```

How can i give the user a selection of three options in the value field?

Comment: You want to force him to type one of three predefined values ? Why don't you use `<select>` ?

Comment: @Teneff Where do i put the select? (i am new to this)

Comment: You put options .. take a look at the answers below

Comment: Have a look at an introduction to HTML. You'll need to learn the basic semantics and syntax. Once you mastered both you only need to learn about the elements you can use. You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML, although it's a little bit outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<select>` with given `<options>`:

> The `select` element represents a control for selecting among a list of options. ([1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html))

#### Example

```
<select>
 <option>My first option</option>
 <option>My second option</option>
 <option>My third option</option>
</select>
```

See also:

- [MDN: select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select)
- [MDN: option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this :
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp